# Determining whether a CFG is $LL(k)$ for any $k$?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, formal-grammars, context-free, parsing

In [Knuth's original paper on $LR(k)$ grammars](http://classes.engr.oregonstate.edu/eecs/winter2012/cs480/assignments/Knuth-1965-TranslationofLanguages.pdf), he proved that the decision problem "Given a CFG $G$, is there a $k$ such that $G$ is an $LR(k)$ grammar?" is undecidable.

Is there a similar result showing that it is undecidable whether a given CFG is an $LL(k)$ grammar for some choice of $k$?  Or is this problem known to be decidable?

Comment: I know that the $LL(1)$ property can be checked. See [these slides](https://softech.cs.uni-kl.de/twiki/pub/Homepage/CLP_SS09/CFAnalysis1_new.pdf) (48++). Have you tried adapting Knuth's proof to $LL$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is undecidable. It is theorem 11 in [Properties of deterministic top down grammars by Rosenkrantz and Stearns](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=805431). Theorem 12 in the same paper however states that the problem becomes decidable if the grammar is known to be $LR(k')$ for some (possibly different) $k'$.