# why recursive languages does not come under Chomsky hierarchy?

Tags: formal-languages

why recursive languages does not come under Chomsky hierarchy ? why Chomsky did not classified 
 it? any real life resemblance of recursive language something that i can connect it with like regular language are ones which needs finite memory or context free languages are those which can be parsed using single stack .something like that .

Answer (score 2):

The hierarchy is defined in terms of grammars. It is still an open question whether there is a natural grammar formalism for recursive languages (check out [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10124/683)), and certainly no such formalism had been known at the time Chomsky wrote his paper.